# Can't use extension on BuildContext

Tags: flutter

I wrote this code to get access to my global scope more comfortable.

```
extension DepContextExtension on BuildContext {
  IGlobalDependency get global => read<IGlobalDependency>();
}
```

I had this code to use my global dependensy

```
final globalScope = context.read<IGlobalDependency>();
```

I change it to this

```
final globalScope = context.global();
```

but i got error, that method global isn't defined for the type BuildContext. What i did wrong and how i can fix this issue?

I get globalSopce inside WidgetModel Factory from library Elementary

```
MainAppScreenWidgetModel mainAppScreenWidgetModelFactory(BuildContext context) {
  final globalScope = context.global();

  return MainAppScreenWidgetModel(
    MainAppScreenModel(
      globalScope.baseBloc,
    ),
  );
}
```

this factory i put inside my Widget like this

```
class MainAppScreenWidget extends ElementaryWidget<MainAppScreenWidgetModel> {
  const MainAppScreenWidget({
    Key? key,
    WidgetModelFactory wmFactory = mainAppScreenWidgetModelFactory,
  }) : super(key: key, wmFactory);
```

Comment: Did you import the extension file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared a property so to access it just use its name:

```dart
final globalScope = context.global;
```